# CYOA book involving travel and a "pennies from heaven" reference with a sealed envelope full of cash from the neighborhood

Tags: identification-request

I would have read this in the early 1990s, I think. We had several official *Choose Your Own Adventures* books in the house, but I think this one was a different branching choice series. I remember it as a slightly larger book than the typical CYOA book, maybe octavo rather than sextodecimo. The plotline involved at least two people (I think a boy and a girl, maybe related) making a trip, maybe as part of a contest of some sort. When they leave, they're handed a sealed envelope from the neighborhood residents, and told not to open it until they really need help. In one of the branches, disaster strikes, I think maybe involving a boat overturning and them losing most of their supplies, and you're given the option of opening the envelope, whereupon a line similar to the following happens:

> "Hey, you know that saying about 'pennies from heaven'? Well, this is dollars from [neighborhood]!"

I'm 95% sure that he neighborhood name ended in "Street".

Basically, the neighborhood had collected some money and sent it along as an emergency fund. I remember it as a mix of bills and coins, and I'm pretty sure it was American currency. In the book, that money lets the team resupply, and continue to one of the happier endings. I don't remember if there were earlier opportunities to open the envelope in a non-emergency setting that led to disaster, but it feels like something that would have happened in the book.